# Как выделить дату из текстового файла с помощю bash-скрипта?

Tags: bash

Как выделить дату из текстового файла с помощю *bash*-скрипта? Например, из такого текста:

> hello, my name is x, my born date is 30/07/1994
>   today's date is 14/09/2015

Нужно получить только `30/07/1994` и `14/09/2015`.

Comment: Дата всегда в таком формате? Т.е. даты вида 30.07.1994 или 1994/07/30 не интересуют? А если дата будет вставлена, например, так: ...is30/07/1994today... (т.е. без пробела между цифрами и словом)? Или ...is 30/07/19941998? Если даты только как в вопросе и "плохие" строки не интересуют, то получить даты можно, например, так: `grep -oP '\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\b' in.file`,

Comment: а можно по подробнее об -oP '\b\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}\b' етой части?? что за опция -оP, и что там значит b???(d наверное digit?)

Comment: попробывала так, но печатает толко первую дату , а не все((

Comment: `-o` - выводит только то, что нашел, `-P` - perl-совместимый синтаксис, `\b` - граница слова, чтобы не выдирали дату из части строки (например, из строки 123456/12/123345). У меня выводит все, что-то не так видно делаете

Comment: понятно.  я не знала что можна сразу две опции поставить)), спосибо большое))

Answer (score 2):

например, с помощью `grep`:

```
$ echo "hello, my name is x, my born date is 30/07/1994 today's date is 14/09/2015" > file
$ grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]{2}/){2}[[:digit:]]{4}' file
30/07/1994
14/09/2015
```

---

**обновление**

более общее решение, вне зависимости от того, первыми ли идут цифры года или последними. также не играет роли символ-разделитель — он может быть любым.

```
$ echo '2001.05.17, my born date is 30/07/1994 today"s date is 14/09/2015' > file
$ grep -Eo '([[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{4}|[[:digit:]]{4}.[[:digit:]]{2}.[[:digit:]]{2})' file
2001.05.17
30/07/1994
14/09/2015
```

Comment: а если дата не корректно например 52/13/1025 , как можем бибести толко корректние даты???

Comment: ложное срабатывание на `12330/07/199412` или даже `233007199412`

Comment: @user190580, более-менее корректную дату можно получить через регулярку `([0-2]\d|3[01])/(0\d|1[0-2])/\d{4}`. "Корректное" - значит в месяце максимум 31 день, месяцев максимум 12. При этом не проверяется действительное наличие дня в месяце. Например, будет считаться нормальным 30 февраля. И не забываем добавить в начало и конец границу слова `\b`; если возможно склеивание текста и цифр, то вместо границы слова можно использовать `[^0-9]`

Comment: @user190580, *а если дата не корректно* — про корректность у вас в вопросе ничего нет. чётко сформулируйте в вопросе признаки корректности — реализовать нужное регулярное выражение труда не составит. исправить вопрос можно, нажав [править](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/450788/edit).

Comment: @user190580, а чтобы вы представили всю сложность такой формулировки, вот вам ссылка на обсуждение регулярного выражения, выбирающего даты **только** формата `dd/mm/yyyy`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15491894